# Bind custom Checkbox Bool property to variable with Bond

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, binding, swiftbond

I'm using https://github.com/DeclarativeHub/Bond library for binding operations. I have an UIControl class which is a checkbox. It has a proper called `isChecked` . I want to bind a boolean value to this property. However, I'm getting

> Cannot invoke 'bind' with an argument list of type '(to: Bool)'

error when trying to bind it. How can I achieve this?

```
viewModel.isDone.map { $0 }.bind(to: containerView.doneCheckBox.reactive.base.isSelected)
```

Comment: Why you choose this library, you can build your Dynamic object in very easy way

Comment: Because I needed to :)